# Modal login form how to fit it in my current login form?

Tags: php, javascript, joomla, simplemodal

Can somebody please explain me how this code fit in to my current login form?

**This is the Modal code:**

```
<!-- #dialog is the id of a DIV defined in the code below -->
<a href="#dialog" name="modal">My new login form</a>

<div id="boxes">


    <!-- #customize your modal window here -->

    <div id="dialog" class="window">
        <b>Testing of Modal Window</b> | 

        <!-- close button is defined as close class -->
        <a href="#" class="close">Close it</a>

    </div>


    <!-- Do not remove div#mask, because you'll need it to fill the whole screen -->    
    <div id="mask"></div>
</div>




<!-- Start of Login Dialog -->  
<div id="dialog1" class="window">
  <div class="d-header">
    <input type="text" value="username" onclick="this.value=''"/><br/>
    <input type="password" value="Password" onclick="this.value=''"/>    
  </div>
  <div class="d-blank"></div>
  <div class="d-login"><input type="image" alt="Login" title="Login" src="images/login-button.png"/></div>
</div>
<!-- End of Login Dialog -->
```

**This is the form where the code should be fit in:**

```
<form action="index.php" method="post" name="login" id="form-login">
<?php if ($params->get('greeting')) : ?>
    <div>
    <?php if ($params->get('name')) : {
        echo JText::sprintf( 'HINAME', $user->get('name') );
    } else : {
        echo JText::sprintf( 'HINAME', $user->get('username') );
    } endif; ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
    <div align="center">
        <input type="submit" name="Submit" class="button" value="<?php echo JText::_( 'BUTTON_LOGOUT'); ?>" />
    </div>

    <input type="hidden" name="option" value="com_user" />
    <input type="hidden" name="task" value="logout" />
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="<?php echo $return; ?>" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this link...it might help

http://theartofjoomla.com/home/6-layouts/16-layout-overrides-popup-login-box.html

Comment: It's not exactly what I ment, but my knowlwedge stops me at this point. Thanks for your reply, and this sollution will do for now.